# SQL query to retrieve value from a XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table which contains a XML column and my data looks something like this:

```
<Entries>   
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="1" Sequence="1" Deleted="Yes"><Undefined></Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="2" Sequence="1">Non-Purulent</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="4" Sequence="2" Deleted="Yes">Sanguinous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="11" Sequence="2">Odor Present</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="3" Sequence="3">Purulent</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="5" Sequence="3" Deleted="Yes">Serosangiunous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="6" Sequence="4">Sanguineous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="7" Sequence="4" Deleted="Yes">Serosanguineous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="8" Sequence="5">Serous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="10" Sequence="6">Sero-sanguineous</Entry>    
    <Entry Default="No" ValueId="9" Sequence="7">Other</Entry>    
</Entries>
```

I want to retrieve the values which do not have the Deleted = "Yes" attribute. I am very new to using XML queries, so I'll appreciate all the help that I can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing `SQL` as your tags and you really mean **SQL Server** by that - then you can use something like this (assuming your table is called `YourTable` and the column holding the XML is called `XmlColumn` - please **adapt** to your actual situation!):

```
-- define a CTE (Common Table Expression) and extract detail info from XML 
;WITH XmlCte AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        XmlText = XC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
        XmlValueId = XC.value('(@ValueId)[1]', 'int'),
        XmlSequence = XC.value('(@Sequence)[1]', 'int'),
        XmlDeleted = XC.value('(@Deleted)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Entries/Entry') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT
    XmlValueId,
    XmlSequence,
    XmlText
FROM XmlCte
WHERE XmlDeleted IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot marc_s. yes I should have tagged the proper RDBMS here. I will make a note of that. Yes, it is SQL server

Answer (score 0):

As per `marc_s`, please tag your RDBMS

On the offchance you mean SQL Server, here's one way to do it with xquery

```
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('@Sequence', 'varchar(50)') AS Sequence,
  Nodes.node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Value
FROM
    MyTable xyz
    cross apply xyz.XmlColumn.nodes('/Entries/Entry[not(@Deleted="Yes")]') as Nodes(node);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09de6/2)

Note that you'll need to make your xml well defined i.e. `<Undefined>`. will either need to be added to a `CDATA` section, or you'll need to close the tag.